# Is it possible to save Swift 4 smart keypaths to UserDefaults

Tags: swift4, codable

I am trying to save a configuration containing keypaths to `UserDefaults`. I would like to avoid writing a static serializing mechanism.

I am been thinking to use the `Codable` protocol but `KeyPath` does not conform to it.

I tried using `NSCoding`/`Data` mechanism, but no success.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @PGDev I would like to store a parameter of type KeyPath to UserDefaults.